# Dedupe based on custom fields?

Tags: duplicate-contacts

My organization contacts can sometimes share the same email address but I have one custom field that is unique to each organization (registration number) and I want to add this custom field to enhance the unsupervised rule.
The thing is that I don't see this option. I can use any standard field (city, zip code...) but none of my custom fields appear.

Is this possible and how? Do I need and extension to do so or to set a parameter somewhere?

EDIT 1 : I use CiviCRM 5.25 on Drupal 7.72

Comment: I just checked on 5.24 on Drupal and could add a custom field to a rule for organisations and save it without problems. Maybe worth adding version and CMS to your post as that may help find an answer

Comment: thanks Rebecca for the reminder! Did you use an existing rule or did you create a new one on purpose?

Comment: I amended (and renamed) the standard unsupervised one for organisations. Maybe worth checking on demo too?

Comment: I tried this way but still can't find the custom fields. Maybe it comes from the fact that it is a sub-type of Organization. I will also test on the demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a custom fieldset, you need to ascribe to "ANY" when your contact type has sub-types. Instead, if ascribed to a particular sub-type (Organization - enterprise, for example), the custom field doesn't show up in dedupe rules :-(

So I found my solution but I would like to have the ability to use custom fields related to a sub-type and not all of them.